# New viewcontroller or new view in the same view controller for pop ups in iOS

Tags: ios, popup

I have worked on some projects done by other developers where I had to handle some modifications. And I got a chance to go through pop ups they have created. Here I am talking about custom pop ups with UILabels, UIButtons, UITextFields etc, not about UIAlertViewControllers or Action Sheets.

Many developers (who were senior to me) have used this approach which is
adding a Visual Effect View in the same view controller and on top of that adding a view which is supposed to show as the pop up. And in runtime they hide and show the view according to the requirement. Here, you won't add more weight to your app, but it gives you headache when you try to edit your UI with constraints.

And some of the developers have used a third party library such as 'MZFormSheetController', where you create a separate view controller and use it as the pop up view. Here, you can add/edit the UI controls, their constraints as you need. But the more you add view controllers to your storyboard, the more you increase the size of your storyboard/app.

I would like to know your opinion and what is the best practice when it comes to pop ups? (Hide and show the view in the same view controller or adding new viewcontroller)

Comment: is this an iPhone app? If Yes then please go on Cocoa & find which is suitable for you as https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=pop

Comment: Hi, I have gone through cocoacontrols and I have used those pop ups. I need to know what's the best approach from above. using a separate view controller or creating a new view on top of the same view controller? thanks in advance!

Comment: @NavodaP hiii need help

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a custom popup to use throughout the app, You can create a separate view or view controller with your custom design which will adjust view according to set value and constraints.

You can either present that view controller on top of any controller (You may not able to present sometime if already opened a model)

IMO, a better option is you can create a separate Window for showing the popup.

Write Show and Hide method which can be accessed from anywhere,
 Add that new window when need to show and remove that window when need to hide.

Alternatively, you can use ready made library with all controls like pod '**[MMPopupView](https://github.com/adad184/MMPopupView)**'

Comment: This can also be a good option as its in swift 3 --> "ETPopupView". BTW Nice approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in viewController 1, when you click a button :

```
   let ShareVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShareVC") as! ShareVC
   ShareVC.image = returnFinalImage()
   self.addChildViewController(ShareVC)
   ShareVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
   self.view.addSubview(ShareVC.view)
   ShareVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Then just set the alpha value of the second viewController's Main View in `viewDidLoad()` like this :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        self.showAnimate()
}

func showAnimate(){
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    self.view.alpha = 0.0;
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    });
}

func removeAnimate(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0;
    }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
        if (finished)
        {
            self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    });
}

@IBAction func closeAction(_ sender:UIButton) {
    removeAnimate()
}
```

[image]

Or you can modally present your view controller using segues and setting its presentation property to "Over the current context" from the property inspector

[image]

Or from code you can do this :

```
let popup : PopupVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PopupVC") as! PopupVC
 let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popup)
 navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
 self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope this was helpful. Happy coding. :)

Comment: thanks, according to your example it seems you prefer using new view controller as a pop up instead of adding a view on top of same view controller.

Comment: yeah! You got it right!  As you said "Here, you won't add more weight to your app, but it gives you headache when you try to edit your UI with constraints." So these options are best way to escape from those constraint related problem's and more over your screen gets more classified. That's the reason I do this.